# Manufacturer Specific Data Map empty in web bluetooth

Tags: web, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt, web-bluetooth

I am designing a web app that uses manufacturer specific data from a BLE device. The device advertises manufacturer specific data and I can see this when using the chrome internal tools. Note that this packet is advertised and there is no scan response set.

Even using this example: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/watch-advertisements.html does not work. I am using 0xFFFF company ID for testing and I set a prefix in the filters too however the map remains empty and so does the event.manufacturerData object.

I have turned on the relevant experimental flags, namely web Bluetooth and the one to do with permissions. Is this a bug or am I missing something with permissions?

Note that advertisement received events are fired and even filtering by data prefix works.

Answer (score 2):

This question was answered [on GitHub](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/issues/598):

Data in `advertisementreceived` events enabled when `watchAdvertisements()` is filtered based on the parameters passed to `requestDevice()` when permission to access the device was granted. To receive manufacturer data the company ID must be included in the `optionalManufacturerData` option like this:

```js
const manufacturerId = 0x0001;

await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
  acceptAllDevices: true,
  optionalManufacturerData: [manufacturerId],
});
```